# Package does not exist error at a later time

Tags: java, tomcat

My package not getting recognized at a later time.

```
import prasanna.AccountDetails;
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
```

I have also set the classpath

```
C:\csj\S1>set CLASSPATH=.;  
C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\servlet-api.jar;  
C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\jsp-api.jar;  
C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\el-api.jar;  
C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar;  
C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\mongo-java-driver-3.1.0-20150911.172057-81.jar;  
C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\bson-3.0.2.jar;C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\mongodb-driver-3.0.2.jar;  
C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\mongodb-driver-core-3.0.2.jar;  
C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\jstl-1.2.jar;C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\jaxb-api.jar;  
C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\jaxb-impl.jar;C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\JAXP_160.jar;  
C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\w3c-dom.jar;C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\javax.xml.parsers-1_1.jar;  
C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\sax.jar;  
C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\webapps\csj\WEB-INF\classes;
```

But still am getting the same error when I compile,

```
C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\webapps\csj\WEB-INF\classes>javac -d . AccountDetails.java
C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\webapps\csj\WEB-INF\classes>javac CreateAccountFinal.java
```

> CreateAccountFinal.java:18: error: package prasanna does not exist
>       import prasanna.AccountDetails;

Comment: i think using `javac CreateAccountFinal.java` will look for the file `C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\webapps\csj\WEB-INF\classes\prasanna\AccountDetails.class` but you have it at `C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\webapps\csj\WEB-INF\classes\AccountDetails.class`. I dont do much command line compiling so I cant be certain but it would what I would look for

Comment: where is your `prasanna` folder and `AccountDetails.class` file?

Comment: I have prasanna folder in C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\webapps\csj\WEB-INF\classes\prasanna and The Accountdetails.class is created inside that folder only. And i have the AccountDetails.java inside C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\webapps\csj\WEB-INF\classes and while comiling I use the command java -d to create the class fie inside prasanna folder.

Comment: When the first time I developed. All worked.